# Is it bad that my CPU fan seems to be going to 0?

Tags: laptop, cpu, fan, cooling

My laptop has recently started making strange noises, which I think is the fan, as if I tap it in the area where the fan is the sound seems to ease off for a moment.

I have opened up the laptop and used compressed air and taken it apart and made sure the area is free of hairs or anything else (it was all pretty clean anyway) so there doesnt seem to be anything that would cause it issues.

Anyway I installed SpeedFan and watched the CPU fan and it seems to be all over the place. The worrying thing here is that it drops down quite a lot.

[image: Fan speed chart while doing very little]

Here is the temp readings from the front page of the app, and I appreciate in laptops the heat dispersion is not going to be as good as a desktop so not sure about the numbers.

[image: Heat info]

Anyway can anyone who has experience here tell me if I should be worried here or is this all perfectly normal and I can just ignore the whirry sound which seems to change in pitch. (I have had this laptop about 3 years and never had any issues with it before so its not a new laptop and I am just not used to fan sound etc).

Comment: You should identify the part number, and replace the fan, only way to prove it is the fan making the noise.  In other words it sounds like a fan is about to fail.  **It also looks like Speedfan is not reporting the correct RPM, 44,549 RPM, is an impossible value for a fan inside a laptop.**

Comment: Fan rpm is dependent on temp of cpu, so yes it will vary depending on heat load.

Comment: Yeah I know it will speed up/slow down based on temp of components, but I would generally expect it to be less erratic, i.e there would be more peaks with a plateau rather than just spikes, as in the first major drop it is at the top then instantly goes to the bottom, which just seems odd I would expect more straight horizontal lines (I could be very wrong and this is fine).